# Why CSS :active on link doesn't make the current page link highlighted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, navigation

I have the following code below for list into master page

```
<div id="header">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="page1.aspx">Page1</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>       ​
```

with css

```
#header a:hover {
    color: #AA1111;
    border-color: #AA1111;
}

#header a:active {
    color: #AA1111;
    border-color:#AA1111;
}
```

but the link doesn't highlight with color when page is actived .

Comment: Both sets have the same colors?

Comment: you have border color, did thy have and border ?

Comment: the first one  when  hover
yes when link active i wont the color stay on menu selected

Comment: Its good if the link color changed on active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:active` does not indicate that the link will be highlighted when the current page is active.

`:active` is the state of the link between mouse click and mouse released on the link. Try holding your mouse down on the link to see for yourself.

To set the current page's link in a different style you will need to either give the current page link a different class and target that class in your CSS.

If you're using .NET I recommend using the various CSS menu adapters / list controls that have the option of specifying the current page menu link class.

Comment: okay I replace my code with that
<li><a href="default.aspx" class="selected">Home</a></li>
with css
 #header a.selected {
  color: #AA1111;
  border-color:#AA1111;
 }

thin add the jquery code

       $(document).ready(function() {
            $('li a').click(function() {
            $("#header a").removeClass();
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            });
        });

and still highlight only Home page !! can you correct me !! 
sorry about my language i not native speaker

Comment: You need .removeClass('selected')

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the meaning of the pseudo-selector `:active`. That css rule will apply when you click on the link. But if that link brings you to a new page, the anchor is no longer active.

What you need to do is add a class to the anchor depending on what page you are on. So, in default.aspx you need to make sure that you have `<a class="active" href="default.aspx">Home</a>`. Then, you will need to change your css rule to `#header a.active`.

Answer (score 0):

The way you may want to setup your page:

```
#header li {}
#header li.active a {color: #AA1111; border-color:#AA1111;} 


<div id="header">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="default.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="page1.aspx">Page1</a></li>

        </ul>
</div>
```

You will need to set the active class on the `li` based on which page.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/HT4U4/